# WebRequest very slow with IPV6 versus Server in IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c#, performance, webrequest

I have a machine configured to use IPv6 by default.

My server is in local on an IPv4 machine.

My issue :

- When I launch the code below, it is executed in 21s.
- When I change IPv6 to IPv4, the code is executed in 127ms.

Where is the mistake?

```
 [TestMethod()]
        public  void Test()
        {
            string url = "myurlserverIPv4";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Proxy = null;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1** : The machine replies with its ipv6 address

**Edit 2** : 
Following "**user3193469**" suggestion I did additional tests

- With the IPv4 address, the code is Executed in 80 ms
- With the mapping of IP address to host name, the code is Executed in 80 ms with the host name. **FIXED**
- Without mapping in host file, the code is Executed in 21ms.

So it's a host name resolution issue .

Comment: All other apps likely will have the same delay. Probably not your code that has the problem. Some config issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "change IPv6 to IPv4" but here are some things you could look at.

Does the hostname in the url have an IPv6 DNS record or is it in your hosts file? Then your machine would try IPv6 first, failing over to ipv4.

Comment: @user3193469, Following your suggestion I did additional tests

- With the IPv4 address, the code is Executed in Few ms

- With the mapping of IP address to host name, the code is Executed in Few ms with the host name.

- Without mapping in host file, the code is Executed in 21ms.
So it's an issue of host name resolution.